# Use ajax to run php script with button click

Tags: php, ajax

I am a hobbyist with limited knowledge of html, javascript, php. I set up a Raspberry Pi microcomputer as a Web server. As a starting point I want to turn on a LED that is connected to the Pi with a button on a Web page. I have the following code that works (name of html file is min.php):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>LED Control</title>
</head>
    <body>
    LED Control:
    <form method="get" action="min.php">
        <input type="submit" value="ON" name="on">
    </form>
    <?php
    $setmode7 = system("gpio mode 7 out");
    if(isset($_GET['on'])){
        $gpio_on = system("gpio write 7 1");
        echo "LED is on";
    }
    else {
        echo "LED is off";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to rewrite the code with an ajax function so that the page does not reload when the button is clicked and here I have problems. I looked at a lot of the posted examples but I just can't get over the hump. I changed the html code as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>LED Control</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="LED_On()">LED On</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"><?script>
<script>
function LED_On(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"LED_On.php",
        type:"GET",
        data:"on"
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The LED_On.php file has the following code and is stored in the same directory as the html file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['on'])){
     $setmode7 = system("gpio mode 7 out");
     $gpio_on = system("gpio write 7 1");
     echo "LED is on";
     }
     else {
        echo "LED is off";
    }
?>
```

Clicking the button does not turn on the LED. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checkin if the ajax code actually sent an HTTP request to the server? checked if it invoked your script? checked if the `system()` calls did anything?

Comment: `data:{on:"true"}`

Comment: might be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"><?script>
` needs to be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Check your code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"><?script>
```

`<?script>` should be changed to `</script>`

Comment: That was it. Thank you.